# Function with Lambda in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following straightforward function in Python 3:

```
def func(i,j):
    return lambda i,j: (i*j)
```

Here's an example of what this function should do:

```
IN: func(4,'Hello')
OUT: ('Hello' 'Hello' 'Hello' 'Hello')
```

However, the actual output is an address in memory where the result is stored. What modification do I need to make?

Comment: Why are you returning a lambda from your function?

Comment: Also, the output you posted would be a syntax error. What's that supposed to be? A tuple containing 4 strings?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I just noticed...

Comment: And what's this got to do with `map`?

Comment: BTW, that function isn't straightforward. Why don't you just do `def func(i, j): return i * j` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the value of `i * j`, then go ahead and return it. A lambda means it returns a function that acts as you want it to. Consider this:

```
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

def func(x, y):
    return lambda x, y: x*y
```

Now let's take a look at a little shell session:

```
>>> mul(4, 'hello')
'hellohellohellohello'
>>> func(4, 'hello')
<function 'lambda' at ...>
>>> f = func(4, 'hello')
>>> f(4, 'hello')
'hellohellohellohello'
```

As you can see, when you use lambda, your function returns a function which, in turn, needs to be called. The arguments `x` and `y` have no correspondence to the arguments in the lambda function.

Since your expected output is a tuple of `x` lots of `y`, use a tuple in your function:

```
def func(i, j):
    return (j,) * i
```